# using subcube in names set in mdx

Tags: filter, mdx

In AdventureWork2012 I write this Query:

```
 select  
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
    [Ship Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] .members on rows
 from 
    [Adventure Works]
 where
    [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].&[Australia];
```

But I want to write this query in a named set in my multidimensional Cube.
I can not use filter function because I can not filter a dimension based on another dimension. I have searched a lot and I found using sub cube like this:

```
select  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
        [Ship Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year] .members on rows
 from 
    (Select [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].&[Australia] on columns from [Adventure Works])
```

But I want to create a named set in my cube in order to showing the Years on axis just for Australia. But I don't know how can I write sub cube in my Named set. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of `Set` you require?

```
 WITH SET [OzzieYears] AS
      NonEmpty(
         [Ship Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].members,
         (
           [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].&[Australia]
          ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] 
         ) 
      )

 SELECT  {} on 0,
         [OzzieYears] on 1
 FROM    [Adventure Works]
```

To create within your cube script follow a walkthrough such as this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166594.aspx

The expression within the `WITH` clause should help. The `NonEmpty` functionreturns a `SET`:

```
NonEmpty(
   [Ship Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].members,
   (
     [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].&[Australia]
    ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] 
   ) 
)
```

I don't play around with cube scripts but I'd guess you could add something like this:

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[OzzieYears]
 AS NonEmpty(
         [Ship Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year].members,
         (
           [Sales Territory].[Sales Territory Country].&[Australia]
          ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] 
         ) 
      ), DISPLAY_FOLDER = 'Sets'  ;
```

Comment: I want to create a named-set into my cube. I can not use With Set ... into it. How can I do this into a names-set in my cube.

Comment: @user3127150 this is a standard way of proto-typing custom measures and sets. Take the expression in the `WITH` clause and go to BIDS and follow a walkthrough such as this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166594.aspx